# Unknown template object: function - Handlebars 2.0.0 and Ember Canary

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have updated my handlebars version to 2.0.0 and my ember version to canary but when I try to run my app the console shows me this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown template object: function
handlebars.runtime.js:455
templatehandlebars.runtime.js:644 
hb.templatecompiled-templates.js:1 (anonymous function)
```

Comment: What steps did you take to get to that point?

Comment: I tried different processes: 1. I updated my bower.json file and set the ember version to canary and the handlebars to 2.0.0. Then I executed bower install and started the server again. 2. Followed the steps specified in the ember website: http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/10/16/handlebars-update.html

Answer (score -1):

Stop your server and start it again after upgrading dependencies.

See: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/9804